# Typeahead getting ID results to undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am facing a strange behavior (I am not a javascript guru :-(). I want to use typeahead for autocompletion, what works fine for me. I have in a modal dialog a form with different kinds of form fields, with an event I want to enable/disable this form components. Works also fine for all except the typeahead input box.

What I have:

**HTML-Snippet:**

```
<div class="row detailRow">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label id="lblAuszubildender" class="detailLabel">Auszubildender:</label>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1">
                <input id="txtAuszubildender" name="txtAuszubildender" class="typeahead form-control detailValue" placeholder="Auszubildender" />   

...

// Instantiate the Typeahead UI
$('#txtAuszubildender').typeahead(
{
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 3
}, 
{
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: apprenticeEngine.ttAdapter()
});
```

**JavaScript Snippet:**

```
$(".detailRow").each(function(){
    var labelElement = $(this).find(".detailLabel");
    var valueElement = $(this).find(".detailValue");
    var labelId = labelElement.attr('id');
    var valueId = valueElement.attr('id');
    filterArray[labelId] = valueId;
});
```

When debugging, for all elements the JavaScript works fine, only the typeahead inputbox doesn`t give his ID.
[image]

But the strange thing is, all informations are given in the input object:
[image]

If I use `var valueId = valueElement.prop('id');`, instead of undefined I become then empty string.

I hope someone can give a hint.

**EDIT:**
I played a little bit with the firebug console. I added the function:

```
function findDetailElements(){
    var filterArray = {};

    $(".detailRow").each(function(){
        var labelElement = $(this).find(".detailLabel");
        var valueElement = $(this).find(".detailValue");
        var labelId = labelElement.attr('id');
        var valueId = valueElement.attr('id');
        filterArray[labelId] = valueId;
    });

    return filterArray;
}
```

Filled a variable:

```
var list = findDetailElements();
console.log(list);
```

**Result: ("txtAuszubildender still missing.")**

```
Object { lblResource: "txtId", lblZustaendigeStelle: "selZustaendigeStelle", lblAuszubildender: undefined, lblBeruf: "selBeruf", lblFachrichtung: "selFachrichtung", lblSchwerpunkt: "selSchwerpunkt", lblBetrieb: "txtBetrieb", lblBeginn: "txtBeginn", lblEnde: "txtEnde", lblStatus: "txtStatus" }
```

BUT when I do something like:

```
$("#txtAuszubildender")
```

I get a result:

```
Object { length: 1, context: HTMLDocument → contract, selector: "#txtAuszubildender", 1 weitere… }
```

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/CNMfL/292/), your code is working fine for me. You should consider using `data-id` instead of `id` for `"txtAuszubildender"`, since `id` is a **unique** identifier and should only be used once in a document.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, unfortunately data-id doesn`t work for me. "txtAuszubildender" is unique. I put little bit more informations into the question.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the issue. Somehow typeahead **creates a second input field** with same class names. Therefore the created second input element comes first and doesn't have an id, this is why I don't get any ID.

[image]

What would be interesting, do I have any control about the class values in that second input element?